# I'm using Oracle for the first time and this code seems to be working for everyone else, but when I put it in my worksheet it's just getting an error

Tags: sql, oracle

Question:

Display the order date and the ship date for all orders that were made April 1 through April 15.  List the order date, ship date, order priority, and ship mode.  Order the results by order_date. Do you notice anything unusual about the data? [Hint: You will need to join the orders and shipping together and use a join statement.  You will need to limit the result set by the date field order_date <= to_date('04/15/2018', 'mm/dd/yyyy'). ]

What I put:

```
select ORDERS.Order_date, SHIPPING.ship_date, ORDERS.order_priority, SHIPPING.ship_mode from orders
join shipping on ORDERS.order_Date = SHIPPING.Ship_Date
where order_date between to_date ('04/01/2018','mm/dd/yyyy')
and to_date ('04/15/2018','mm/dd/yyyy')
order by order_date
```

The error I'm getting:

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: what "worksheet?"

Comment: Is that homework, or are you following a book (self study)? Either way, it seems that the practice problem assumes the existence of two tables, ORDERS and SHIPPING. The error message tells you that at least one of these tables does not exist IN YOUR SCHEMA, and there are no aliases by these names to tables in other users' schemata. You need to create and populate the tables (likely using a script) first. It's also possible that they exist, under a generic user - then you must connect to the database AS THAT USER, or qualify the table names with the schema name.

Comment: Since you are obviously a beginning student, and this is obviously a homework question, please consider a few suggestions from a an old war horse who recently retired after 40+ years in this business. 1) Do not write code as one hot-mess of run-on text.  For a SQL statement, each key word (SELECT, FROM, WHERE, etc) should start a new line. 2) each item in a list (column names, table names, WHERE conditions) should start a new line and indented from the previous key word.   These rules will make your code much easier to read, understand, and debug.

Comment: What Database-Client are you using? Please edit your question and add that information.

Answer (score 0):

You have already made a synonym.. Please try with schema  . select ORDERS.Order_date from your_schema.ORDERS

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a synonym for the Orders table like this:
CREATE SYNONYM orders FOR orders;

Comment: That will give "ORA-01471: cannot create a synonym with same name as object".

Comment: You have already made a synonym.. Please try with schema  . select ORDERS.Order_date from your_schema.ORDERS

Comment: I haven't made any synonyms. I am pointing out why your answer won't work.

Comment: Please try with schema . select Order_date from your_schema.ORDERS

Comment: The issue is with `create synonym`, not with any `select`. You can't create a private synonym with the same name as a table in the same schema, because that would create two objects with the same name in the same schema.